# What is level of normalization HR Oracle Sample Database?

Tags: oracle, normalization

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88804

Is it third normal form or maybe fourth normal form ? I know that mostly database have only third normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the LOCATION having a STATE_REGION column in it, as well as a COUNTRY_ID, I'd say that it fails the test for second normal form because the same STATE_COUNTRY could be associated with multiple countries through an error in updating the table.